# Unable to display content using search filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Unable to show results using `filter: search`. when I remove the filter then the data is displayed properly.

```
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="workOrderController">
    <div class="row m-t-20 user_work_area_dashboard">
        <div class="col-md-3  text-center" >
            <ul class="tabs_left_dashboard">
                <li><a ng-click="search.status = ''" href="">ALL PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="search.status = 'PORTFOLIO'" href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="search.status = 'CATEGORY'" href="">NOTIFICATIONS</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="search.status = 'IN PROGRESS'" href="">RUNNING PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="search.status = 'COMPLETED PROJECTS'" href="">COMPLETED PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li ng-if="$parent.role == 'admin'" href=""><a ng-click="search.status = 'OPEN'">OPEN PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li ng-if="$parent.role == 'admin'" href=""><a ng-click="search.status = 'ASSETS'">ASSETS</a></li>
                <li ng-if="$parent.role == 'admin'" href=""><a ng-click="search.status = 'JOB REQUESTS'">JOB REQUESTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end of tab buttons-->

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div  cg-busy="{promise: myPromise}">
                <div class="list_projects_section_in_dashboard">
                    <ul class="list_of_projects row">
                        <li class="col-md-15 col-sm-3" ng-repeat="wd in workOrdersList | filter:search">
                            <a ng-click=" viewProject(wd)" href=" ">
                                <img src="./images/projectthumb.jpg" />
                                <h4>{{wd.name}}</h4>
                            </a>
                            <p>Status: {{wd.status}}</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--end of tab content-->
```

There is no error but it just doesn't display any content. Its working with`ng-repeat` but somehow not working when I use `filter`. When I inspected the DOM it shows:

```
<ul class="list_of_projects row">
    <!-- ngRepeat: wd in workOrdersList | filter:search -->
</ul>
```

Why is it getting commented out? Strange. I am not able to figure out

Comment: Are you sure workOrderList exists in your $scope?

Comment: @MattanBitner Yes I am able to print it in the console when controller(page) is loaded

Comment: @MattanBitner If I use `ng-repeat` it works so it must be in scope if I am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Changing the filter from `filter: search` to `filter: search.status` worked.